# Twitter Auth URL

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

Im trying to authenticate users using twitter and Javascript but I dont want to use a plugin because im already using laravel for the backend and other twitter auths through socialite. But I need to open a new window and I can only do this is javascript.

With all due respect i've looked around for about an hour now so sending me a link to the twitter API might not be helpful

**Question**

What is the twitter authentication url and what parameters do I need to pass?